# Dynamically added TextView has zero width and height

Tags: android, view, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a programatically created RelativeLayout as shown in code below. The RelativeLayout has same width and height of an EditText and lies above the EditText. I add a programatically created TextView to it with certain width and height.

```
overlay = new RelativeLayout(context);
overlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //NO I18N
viewGroup.addView(overlay);
overlay.bringToFront();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) overlay.getLayoutParams());
lp.width = getMeasuredWidth();
lp.height = getMeasuredHeight();
Log.d(TAG, "initOverlay: width " + lp.width + " height " + lp.height);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.formulaView);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.fxImg);
lp.setMargins(0, ((int) Util.dptopx(context, 1) + getTotalPaddingTop()), 0, ((int) Util.dptopx(context, 1) + getTotalPaddingBottom()));
overlay.setLayoutParams(lp);
setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
overlay.setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
overlay.requestLayout();
```

The first time when the TextView is added, the views are shown with specified width and height. But when i remove the TextView from RelativeLayout and add a new TextView again, the TextView is not being shown. It has zero width and height though i'm setting a width and height. What could possibly be the problem?

TextView

```
textview = new CustomTextView(edittext.getContext());
Editable editable = edittext.getEditableText();
String spantext = editable.subSequence(startidx, endidx).toString();
float[] location = Util.determineTextViewLocation(startidx, endidx);
textview.setText(spantext);
textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, edittext.getTextSize());
textview.setX(location[0]);
textview.setY(location[1]);
textview.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int) location[2], (int) location[3]));
textview.setPadding(0, ((int) location[4]), 0, 0);
overlay.addView(textview);
Log.d(TAG, "width "+textview.getWidth()+" height "+textview.getHeight()+" view"+textview);
```

Edit: The TextView's onMeasure() method is never getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
     XTextView textView= new XTextView(this);
     textView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,500));
     textview.setText("Sample");
     textview.setX(location[0]);
     textview.setY(location[1]);
     textview.setLayoutParams(lp);
     overlay.addView(textview);
     textview.requestLayout();
```

Also for overlay don't use getLayoutParams() method. Use

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```

Comment: it's still having 0 width and height

Comment: Um thats not as per my requirement.. The overlay is a relative layout that I'm positioning above an EditText. It has to have the exact same measurement of the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What fixed it for me was to add the textview to its parent first, then post a runnable to the text view with

```
textView.post(new Runnable() { ... })
```

and then set the layout params within that runnable

I know this question is super old but just in case anyone else runs into this problem :)